# Applying value from one column to a new column

Tags: r, data-structures

I have a data frame with several columns each corresponding to a rating for different stimuli. I also have columns indicating the order in which each participant saw each item. Each row is one participant.

```
x <- data.frame("post1" = c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA), #stimuli ratings columns
                "post2" = c(3, 1, NA, NA, 4),
                "post3" = c(NA, 3, 1, 4, NA),
                "firstpost" = c("post3", "post1", "post3", "post6", 
                 "post4"), #stimuli order columns
                "secondpost" = c("post2", "post3", "post1", "post4", 
                 "post1"))
```

I want to make another set of columns that has the values (ratings) from the first set of columns ("post1" etc.) in the order that they saw the stimuli - for example, if they saw post 3 first, the new column would have their rating of post 3. Something like this:

```
firstpostrating <- c(4, 1, 2, 3, 2)
secondpostrating <- c(1, 3, 3, 2, 1)
```

I need a way to grab the value from the corresponding stimuli column for each of the stimuli they see. The result I'm hoping for is columns for first, second, third stimuli and the corresponding rating - so I can look at order effects.

Any help writing a function for this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your sample data doesn't work, it's not a valid R object. Please update it so that it works without error.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the sample data code!

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide one solution.
The example data `x` I used is a little different with yours. Because for consistence, the example data shouldn't include `post6` and `post4`.

```r
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(post1 = c(1, NA, 2, 3, 4), #stimuli ratings columns
                post2 = c(3, 1, NA, 2, 5),
                post3 = c(2, 3, 1, 4, 5),
                firstpost = c("post3", "post1", "post3", "post2", 
                 "post1"), #stimuli order columns
                secondpost = c("post2", "post3", "post2", "post3", 
                 "post1"))
x
#>    post1 post2 post3 firstpost secondpost
#> 1:     1     3     2     post3      post2
#> 2:    NA     1     3     post1      post3
#> 3:     2    NA     1     post3      post2
#> 4:     3     2     4     post2      post3
#> 5:     4     5     5     post1      post1
x[,`:=`(firstpostrate  = get(firstpost),
        secondpostrate = get(secondpost)),
  by = post1]
x
#>    post1 post2 post3 firstpost secondpost firstpostrate secondpostrate
#> 1:     1     3     2     post3      post2             2              3
#> 2:    NA     1     3     post1      post3            NA              3
#> 3:     2    NA     1     post3      post2             1             NA
#> 4:     3     2     4     post2      post3             2              4
#> 5:     4     5     5     post1      post1             4              4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>